# WordPress menu walker item has "wrong" fields

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I'm trying to create (my first) menu walker for a WordPress theme (based on _s) but I can't get a working menu as output. I found several examples on the web but no one seems to work properly. The $item variable looks really strange. If I do a

```
class My_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
   function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($item);
       echo "</pre>";
       ... my not working code here
   }
}
```

I get a WP-Post output from the dump with no $item->url, no $item->title etc. I do have a $item->guid, $item->post_title. I call the walker in header.php via:

```
$walker = new My_Menu_Walker;
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary', 
    'menu_id' => 'primary-menu',
    'walker' => $walker
));
```

I guess I'm doing something really stupid but right now I can't see what.